# Combine n elements in first half of list with elements in other half of a list, if number of elements in a list is greater than 2

Tags: python, list, element

I have a problem with dealing with elements in a list. To be precise in a list of lists. For example, I have list of elements that are read from a file:

```
list_1 = [['void', None], ['uint8', 'f_MbistTestType_u8'], ['uint8', 'uint32', 'f_MbistTestType_u8', 'f_chip_id_u32'], ['void', None], ['void', None], ['void', None], ['void', None]]
```

In this case third element has more than two elements. I want to switch element 2 with element 3. So it would look like this:

```
list_1[2] = ['uint8', 'f_MbistTestType_u8', 'uint32', 'f_chip_id_u32']
```

If there would be 6 elements i.e.

```
list_example = ['uint8', 'uint32', 'void', 'f_chip_id_u32', 'f_MbistTestType_u8', None]
```

After the operation it should look like this:

```
list_example_sorted = ['uint8', 'f_chip_id_u32', 'uint32', 'f_MbistTestType_u8', 'void', None]
```

Right now I know how to get those elements in case I have only one occurrence of more than 2 elements, but don't know how to switch their places and also what to do in case I have more than one occurrence:

```
for elements in list_1:
print(elements)
if len(elements) > 2:
    list_el = elements
    print(list_el)
```

I tried to pop them out and append, but it won't scale well with more than 4 elements.

I tried to use swap function, but it seems that it doesn't work or I used it wrong?

[image]

Comment: What should happen if list length is odd?

Comment: Structure of a file that those elements are taken from makes it impossible to have odd numbers of elements.

Comment: Do you only want to swap the second element of the left half with the first element of the right half?

Comment: No, the desired output in this example would be: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2].

Comment: Okay, so going by this I assume that for a list of 8 elements, i.e. `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]` you'd expect the outcome to be `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`

Comment: Exactly, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by an input of `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]` with the desired output `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`, i.e. you want the first element of the left half followed by the first element of the right half and so forth.
To make it more obvious:

- `input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
- `output = [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]`

Define a function `combine_inplace` that combines the ith element of the left half with the ith element of the right half of `l`:

```py
def combine_inplace(l):
    mid = len(l) // 2
    ptr = 0
    for left, right in zip(l[:mid], l[mid:]):
        l[ptr], l[ptr+1] = left, right
        # Increment pointer ptr by 2 for the next combination
        ptr += 2
```

- `combine_inplace` mutates the passed list `l`
- left half and right half are created using slice operator
- use `zip` to iterate over both list
- increment `ptr` by 2 to get to the next list indices for `l`

If you don't want to mutate the list itself you can instead create a new list `combined` that is returned by the function `combine`:

```py
def combine(l):
    mid = len(l) // 2
    combined = []
    for left, right in zip(l[:mid], l[mid:]):
        combined.extend((left, right))
    return combined
```

- Does not mutate the passed list `l`
- Initialise empty list `combined` to store the combined values
- use `zip` to iterate over both list halves
- Returns the list `combined`

This uses the same logic as `combine_inplace` but you keep the original list intact.

Both functions combine the elements of the left half with the right half of a given list. The only difference is that with `combine` you have to store the returned list in a variable to access it.

```py
>> l = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
>> combine_inplace(l)
>> print(l)
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
>> input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>> output_list = combine(input_list)
>> print(output_list)
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Now using either `combine` or `combine_inplace` to combine elements of lists with a `length > 2` inside a list:

```py
ll = [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
# Non-destructive way using combine to create a new list comb_ll
comb_ll = []
for el in ll:
    if len(el) > 2:
        el = combine(el)
    comb_ll.append(el)

# Mutates the original list
for i in range(len(ll)):
    if len(ll[i]) > 2:
        combine_inplace(ll[i])
```

In both cases you'll get the same result:

```py
>> print(comb_ll)
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]]
>> print(ll)
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2, 1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]]
```

Comment: Thank You for answer @Wolric . I implemented swap function that You have provided, but it seems it doesn't work and I don't really know why. Please see updated question for a picture.

Comment: Your code fails as `swap` returns a new list. It doesn't swap the elements in place.
So you need to catch the returned list in a new variable

Comment: Thanks, my bad, I didn't catch that. Now it works, but my desired output would be list_after_swap = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

Comment: Using the example `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]` hid a logical error I had. Going by your example with six elements it's more obvious using elements `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` so now the function `combine` produces the desired output `[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]`